# AWS Cloudwatch not triggering on API calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to make a rule trigger on any API call for creation, but I haven't had any success.

I have another rule that triggers whenever and ec2 instance is running which works, but this rule does not trigger for RunInstances although I see the cloudtrail logs with RunInstances in the API log.

I have made a CloudWatch log from the cloudtrail and see the events that should be triggering it, but they don't. Is there a step I am missing? What are the necessary components to have CloudWatch properly trigger on API calls?

The rule mentioned:

```
 {
      "source": [
        "aws.cloudtrail"
      ],
      "detail-type": [
        "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
      ],
      "detail": {
        "eventSource": [
          "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
        ],
        "eventName": [
          "CreateUserPool",
          "CreateImage",
          "CreateCacheCluster",
          "RunInstances",
          "CreateActivation",
          "RunJobFlow ",
          "CreateVault",
          "CreateDeliveryStream",
          "CreateStream",
          "CreateCluster",
          "CreateDBInstance",
          "CreateHostedZone",
          "CreateBucket",
          "CreateLaunchConfiguration",
          "CreateStack",
          "CreateEnvironment",
          "CreateWorkspaces"
        ]
      }
    }
```

To add more detail here is the other rule I used to test CloudWatch

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "running"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the log of the startInstances and the following Lambda function running.
[image]

Cloudtrail of the the lambda function specifically which functions normally.

[image: Lambda function log]

Here is the API call which should also initiate it according to the rule, but it does not.
  [image]

Hopefully these images make it clearer as to what I am having trouble with.

P.S. I didn't know how much info I should consider confidential, so I over censored

Comment: I had a misundertanding of what AWS API calls from Cloudtrail meant when looking at cloudtrail. I now believe it is only commands associated with that service in this case cloudtrail, which would not have RunInstances at all. I'm testing other options to get the results I want.

Comment: If anyone is still interested in doing this, it is possible to have multiple events within a rule. They do have to be explicitly stated, e.g. ec2, s3, and etc. There is no wildcard functionality. Also the JSON formats will differ between events of different resources, so retrieving a specific parameter will require hard coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the rule I created. I thought "AWS API calls from Cloudtrail" when using the cloudtrail Service meant all the information stored in Cloudtrail. That does not seem to be the case.

As I mention in my comment, I am looking for other solutions for my problem, but I will make a separate question for that. Thanks!